# How to use sidekiq on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, sidekiq, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to use sidekiq on Bluemix. I think that I'm on the right track, but it's not working completely.

I have an app with Sinatra that uses sidekiq jobs to make many actions. I set the following line in my `manifest.yml` file:

`command: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT && bundle exec sidekiq -r ./server.rb -c 3`

I thought that with this command sidekiq will run, However, when I call the endpoint that creates a job, it's still on the "Queue" section on the Sidekiq panel.

What actions do I need to take to get sidekiq to process the job?

PS: I'm beginner on Bluemix. I'm trying to migrate my app from Heroku to Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

**Straightforward answer to this question "as asked":**

Your start-up command does not evaluate a second part, the one after '&&'. If you try starting that in your local environment, the result'll be the same. The server will start up and the console will simply tail the server logs, not technically evaluating to true until you send it a kill signal (so the part after '&&' will never run at the same time).

Subbing that with just '&' sort-of-kinda fixes that, since both will run at the same time.

> command: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT & bundle exec sidekiq

What is not ideal with that solution? Eh, probably a lot of stuff. The biggest offender though: having two processes active at the same time, only one of them expected and observed ( the second one ).

Sending '(bluemix) cf stop' to the application instance created by the manifest with this command stops only the observed one before decommissioning the instance - in that case we can not be sure that the first process freed up external resources by properly sending notifications or closing the connections, or whatever.

---

**What you probably could consider instead:**

**1. Point one.**
Bluemix is a CF implementation, and with a quick manifest.yml deploy, there is nothing preventing you from having the app server and sidekiq workers run on separate instances.

**2. Better shell.**

> command: sh -c 'command1 & command2 & wait'

**3. TBD, probably a lot of options, but I am a beginner as well. **

Answer (score 0):

Separate app instances on CloudFoundry for your rack-based application and your workers would be preferable because you can then:

- Scale web / workers independently (more traffic? Just scale the web application)
- Deploy each component independently, if needed
- Make sure each process is health-checked

The downside of using `&` to join commands, as suggested in the other answer, is that the first process will launch in the background. This means you won't have reliable monitoring and automatic restarts if the first process crashes.

There's a slightly out of date example on the CloudFoundry website which [demos using two application manifests](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/ruby/ruby-tips.html#workers) (one for web, one for workers) to deploy each part independently.